# How to configure the data trigger function?

Tags: azure-stream-analytics

The case: we have an agent which send data to eventhub, we use the event hub as input for the aggregation and calculation using ASA. When the agent has some problems, it will send a value to the eventhub(maybe serval days send an error value), we want to write a value to the output when we receive the agent error value, so how to solve this problem? We cannot using window because it is data triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to write to the same output (sink), you can define replicated output in ASA (same as the existing output as it does not support 2 queries writing to same output). Define another query that just consumes the error events only and writes to second output defined (but to the same physical output location) and this would be a pass-through query "select * ...". hope that helps.
thanks
Venkat

Comment: thanks, another query also need the SAS windows,it means 5min or each second we take a once, some times it will make a delay when we got an error, later we will got it from the output.

Comment: you don't need a window for the second query, use select * from ...query and it processes as the input comes in.